# Shift the curve legen of a auc curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am begineer to python. I am trying to plot a `auc curve for 10 fold validation`. The implementation is, [like this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8xDhJgyysS/),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
# #############################################################################
# Data IO and generation
# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]
# #############################################################################
# Classification and ROC analysis
# Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)
tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
    classifier.fit(X[train], y[train])
    viz = plot_roc_curve(classifier, X[test], y[test],
                         name='ROC fold {}'.format(i),
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
    interp_tpr = np.interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
    tprs.append(interp_tpr)
    aucs.append(viz.roc_auc)
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
        label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
ax.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
        label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
        lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
ax.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

ax.set(xlim=[-0.05, 1.05], ylim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       title="Receiver operating characteristic example")
ax.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

And the `output is`,

[image]

How can i shift the values of 10 auc values (ROC fold {1..10}) `to more right for better visualization`?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do here is to use matplotlib's `bbox_to_anchor` parameter when plotting the legend, which allows you to manually place the legend box so that it does not overlap with your charts.

Just replace

```
ax.legend(loc="lower right")
```

with

```
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

Then you will get:

[image: legend to the side]